# How do I increase the width of an NSScroller in a WebView

Tags: cocoa, webview, nsscroller

I am developing a web browser for a touch-screen kiosk and the scrollbars on the WebView are impractically small for being able to scroll using them on a touch-screen.
Is there anyway to increase the size of them?

I can get a reference to the vertical scroller using

```
[[[[[webView mainFrame] frameView] documentView] enclosingScrollView] verticalScroller]
```

Comment: Ew, what a horrible UI. Far better to not have scrollbars a la iOS.

Comment: Well it was far easier to implements wider scollbars than to implement scrolling the screen using touch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out you can use categories to override the scroller width method for all NSScrollers.

Eg. In NSScroller-MyScroller.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface NSScroller (MyScroller)

+ (CGFloat)scrollerWidth;
+ (CGFloat)scrollerWidthForControlSize: (NSControlSize)controlSize;

@end
```

In NSScroller-MyScroller.m:

```
#import "NSScroller-MyScroller.h"
#define SCROLLER_WIDTH 30.0

@implementation NSScroller (MyScroller)

+ (CGFloat)scrollerWidth {
    return SCROLLER_WIDTH;
}

+ (CGFloat)scrollerWidthForControlSize: (NSControlSize)controlSize {
    return SCROLLER_WIDTH;
}

@end
```